# Karma plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, karma-runner

Why I can not see [this](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7287?pr=phpStorm&offset=15&max=15) **Karma** plugin in **intellij IDEA 12** plugins?

And if I download it I can not install it from the disk. It says that this plugin **"is not compatible"**

But I guess it works in `WebStorm`.

The Point is.. I just thought if one bought `IntelliJ IDEA` licence then he/she can work either with **web** or with **Java** **in full**. Isn't that 'IntelliJ IDEA' should be able to have all stuff that `WebStrom` has if one want to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is not compatible with IDEA 12, only IDEA 13. If you look at the "Since Build" and Until Build" values, it shows what build number range the plugin is compatible with. IntelliJ IDEA uses a dual number build number. The first is the branch number and the second is the build on that branch. For the most part, the first two digits of the branch number correspond with the IDEA version. For example, IDEA v12.1.6 is build 129.1359. V 12.0 was build 123.72.

The first release of the plug-in you asked about had a valid build range of 130.1167 through    131 (i.e. it was valid for all of the 130 branch). These were IDEA 13 EAP (i.e. beta) builds. The latest plug-in release is for builds 133 through 132 (i.e. the 133 branch). IDEA 13.0, released yesterday, is build 133.193.

Note that if you purchased your IntelliJ IDEA 12 license on or after Oct 30, 2013, it is valid for IDEA 13. (See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/30490508-IntelliJ-IDEA-12-key-doesn-t-work-in-13-version for details)